# Rails recommended way to deal with commonly used html boilerplate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For instance, in the table below, I am using the actions over and over throughout my app, and I am not quite sure how to DRY it up, either partial views or rails helpers (which don't seem great for dealing with html fragments)...(I am using Slim btw)

I would like to be able to do something like:
= edit_button (path, 'optional display text', 'optional extra classes)

```
table.grid
    thead
        tr
            th Researcher
            th Email Address
            th Last Activity
            th Activated
            th Failed logins
            th Locked
            th Actions
    tbody
        - @users.each do |user|
            tr
                td
                    = "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}"
                td
                    = user.email
                td
                    | About 1 day ago
                td
                    | Yes
                td
                    = user.failed_logins_count
                td
                    | No
                td
                    div.actions
                        a.small.button.edit href=edit_user_path(user)
                            i.general.foundicon-edit
                            | Edit
                        a.small.button.delete href=user_path(user) method='delete' data-confirm='Are you sure?'
                            i.general.foundicon-trash
                            | Delete
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using partials are the rails recommended way to DRY up your view. See the first few lines of [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) page.